# Why has the zemiroh על אהבתך אשתה גביעי fallen out of favour?

Tags: shabbat, history, internet, song-poetry, shabbat-songs

We used to sing a zemiroh, I believe by Rabbi Yehudah HaLevi, which started, על אהבתך אשתה גביעי. This zemiroh does not appear in current zemiros books. (1) Do you have an online text of it? (2) Why has it fallen out of favour?

Comment: I just found the answer to part (1). See http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/314.html

Comment: +1. Re "This zemiroh does not appear in current zemiros books": Have you checked _S'faradi_ ones? They have many _z'miros_ (_pizmonim_, as they call them) that _Ashk'nazim_ don't tend to.

Comment: @msh10 Thank you; point taken. It used to appear in some ashkenazi zemiros books; but seems to have been dropped.

Comment: Nitpick: Isn't the singular form "zemer" rather than "zemiroh"?

Comment: @Dave, I've usually heard _zemer_ used to refer to one of them and _z'miros_ for more, but I guess the singular of _z'miros_ would have to be _z'mira_ (like _chakira_, _y'shiva_, _asiya_, etc.), with _zemer_ being a different noun. (The plural of _zemer_ would, I suppose, be _z'marim_ (like _y'ladim_, _b'gadim_, etc.) or possibly _z'maros_ (for which I think there are analogues, too, though I can't think of one right now).

Comment: Consider breaking up the two parts of the question. As it stands now, it appears too broad.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/314.html

This is a link to the words of this song.

Comment: Dead link. [15]